# Is there a cgvg-like command for mac?

Tags: macos, grep

Is there a nice cgvg-like tool for Mac (it's a simple grep-and-open utility)?  I tried installing cgvg, and it can't find the no-longer-used find.pl from Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cgvg author here -- I haven't touched it (or Perl) in over a decade, but I'll take a look at putting out a new release that fixes this in the not too distant future.  In the meantime, grab source for the libperl4-corelibs-perl package from somewhere like

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/libperl4-corelibs-perl

Grab the orig src tarball, untar, grab the find.pl file within and stick it in the Perl search patch somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yeah, the sooner the fix the better!  It's a great tool.

Comment: Alright, version 1.6.3 should take care of the problem.  You can get it from https://github.com/uzi/cgvg/releases/tag/v1.6.3 ...

Thanks for the love!

Comment: Oh, wow.  Great!  Thank you.  I'm definitely a fan of the tool.  You should submit a PR to homebrew for it!